# Excel - consolidate with OR operation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas, consolidation

I have in a sheet a table like so:

```
+------+---------+
| Name | Boolean |
+------+---------+
| A    | true    |
| B    | true    |
| B    | false   |
| C    | false   |
| C    | false   |
| A    | false   |
+------+---------+
```

But in another sheet I need to consolidate it by having a column with unique name and another with the OR of all column Boolean matching the unique name.
Like so:

```
+------+---------+
| Name | Boolean |
+------+---------+
| A    | true    |
| B    | true    |
| C    | false   |
+------+---------+
```

I tried Consolidate (no OR operation) and also Index/Match combo, and I couldn't make it work with array-formulas.
I more or less succeed with an Pivot table, but the result wasn't much satisfactory.

There's a simple way to do this that I can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,TRUE)>0
```

Comment: It works!  Thanks.
In the end, my biggest problem was that the column wasn't converting the text into boolean, so the comparisons wasn't well done.